# Storing information in iOS calendar app using core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have already created a calendar application using one view controller and many day views and month views. I would like to now incorporate core data so I can store information for each day if the user selects a certain day. I have not used a UITableViewController or a UICollectionViewController so I don't think a NSFetchedResultsController would work.
What method would you suggest for me to use core data to store information using the calendar I made? I am new to core data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSFetchedResultsController` regardless of how you display the information. The "method" to "store information" has nothing to do with how you access it.

I would strongly suggest you learn some basic UIKit techniques, such as using `UICollectionView`. In conjunction with `NSFetchedResultsController` you will get a lot of optimizations for free.